# Golang's Delve can't find packages located in parent folder

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, delve

**Problem:**
I'm using gb to build the project. It recursively checks all folders to get vendor, external and main.go files.
Delve doesn't do this so when I ssh into the docker image and try to run the dlv server on the root of the project it says that it cannot find go files. If I try with src/cmd/project/main.go it says it cannot find all the other packages.

1. What version of Delve are you using (`dlv version`)?
   dlv1.1.0
2. What version of Go are you using? (`go version`)?
   go1.9.2
3. What operating system and processor architecture are you using?
   Docker 18.06.1-ce in Mint 19
4. What did you do?
   dlv debug src/cmd/project/main.go-l 0.0.0.0:2345 --headless=true --log=true -- server
5. What did you expect to see?
   Delve running
6. What did you see instead?

   src/cmd/project/main.go:4:2: cannot find package "external/nexudus" in any of:
       /usr/local/go/src/external/nexudus (from $GOROOT)
       /go/src/external/nexudus (from $GOPATH)
   src/cmd/project/main.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/jinzhu/gorm" in any of:
       /usr/local/go/src/github.com/jinzhu/gorm (from $GOROOT)
       /go/src/github.com/jinzhu/gorm (from $GOPATH)
   src/cmd/project/main.go:9:2: cannot find package "gopkg.in/intercom/intercom-go.v2" in any of:
       /usr/local/go/src/gopkg.in/intercom/intercom-go.v2 (from $GOROOT)
       /go/src/gopkg.in/intercom/intercom-go.v2 (from $GOPATH)
   exit status 1
7. EXTRA
   **My configuration file (docker/web-dev):**
   ...

   VOLUME /project/app/contracts

   VOLUME /project/pkg

   VOLUME /project/src

   VOLUME /project/vendor

**My docker-compose file:**

```
web:

  build: .

  dockerfile: docker/web-dev

  working_dir: /project

  command: /go/bin/reflex --regex='\.go$$' --inverse-regex='_test\.go$$' --start-service -- sh -c 'gb build all && ./bin/project server'

  ports:

  - 6262:6262

  volumes:

  - ./pkg:/project/pkg

  - ./src:/project/src

  - ./vendor:/project/vendor

  - ./app:/project/app

  - ./app/contracts:/project/app/contracts
```

Comment: go to the project's git directory and run `go build`, it will fetch missing dependencies.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean. The project itself builds with gb. Honestly I'm not sure if it's even possible to do go build. The project folders are: /app, /bin, /pkg, /src, /vendor.  Main is in ./src/cmd/microlab/main.go